# Using prisma with postgreSql but I have a field in model starting with number

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

I'm using prisma with postgreSql with my node.js project and I have a field in my model start with number but prisma is not allow me to start a field with number in the model. Any solution for this or should I use another ODM. Any suggestions.

```
3rd_party_web_ordering Boolean[]
3rd_pty_delivery_to_go String[]
3rd_pty_customer_loyalty String[]
3rd_pty_gift_cards String[]
3rd_pty_reservations String[]
3rd_pty_inventory String[]
3rd_pty_scheduling String[]
3rd_pty_payments String[]
3rd_pty_beverage_services String[]
```

Error is `Error validating: The name of a Field must not start with a number.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use a string in the beginning instead.

Example: third_party_web_ordering Boolean[]